# Error: partition table requires a separate partition for boot loader code (EFI issue)

Tags: installation, uefi, mac, macbook-pro, boot-partition

### The Issue

I'm trying to install [Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit, Mac alternate)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04.2-alternate-amd64+mac.iso) on my 13" MacBook Pro [(model 7,1. Mid-2010)](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP583). The MacBook Pro is running OSX 10.8.3 and I'm trying to make it dual-bootable (i.e., so I can boot into Ubuntu or OSX). When booting from the live CD and selecting "Try Ubuntu," I made the allegedly necessary partition tables and was ready to install. Through the installation process, I selected my newly created "ext4" partition, changed it (in the installer) to "Use as ext4 journaling file system," and pressed continue. However, the following window popped up:

[image: The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as a "Reserved BIOS boot area" and should be at least 1 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition booted on /boot. If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, boot loader installation may fail later, although it may still be possible to install the boot loader to a partition.]

Below is a snapshot of my partition table in GParted.

[image: GParted partition table setup]

Below is a snapshot of the installation window.

[image: Installation window]

---

### The Hypothesis

[@Seth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth) and I are geared towards thinkhing this is an issue with Ubuntu not detecting that my computer is using EFI instead of BIOS. I think that if we somehow get Ubuntu to recognize that I'm running a computer that uses EFI, the installation will run smoother. However, because I'm running on a MacBook Pro, users who've had similar problems with Windows won't have the same solutions for me (or other future problem-havers) to use.

---

### Things Tried & Investigated

Below are things that I've tried and looked into. I'll be updating it as this issue progresses.

1. I've tried researching this issue, and came across [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186413/how-to-boot-from-ubuntu-12-04) as well. After discussing this issue with people in the chat room, though, I'm -- *we're* -- pretty sure it's a hardware issue.
2. Additionally, I tried [this wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_or_Legacy_mode), but the wiki looks geared towards Windows and, again, I'm pretty sure this is a hardware-specific issue. **Update:** I went ahead and tried the section I linked to, and it didn't entirely workout. When following the instructions, I wasn't able to click onto the "GRUB location" tab because it was disabled: [image: grub location disabled]
3. Another *untried* option [@Seth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth) and I went over was bypassing the error, then running the boot-repair program listed above. There are concerns about this being dangerous, though, so I'd be glad to hear another opinion.
4. I've tried the solution provided by [@rod-smith](https://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith). However, as apparent in the comments on his answer, I ran into some issues. When trying the alternate steps under step 10, booting up just got me a blank screen that wouldn't go away (the most recent amount of time that I've spent on that screen was about 40 minutes until I rebooted). Continuing to follow the instructions, before step 18 shows up (which it never does), I get the following error:

   > WARNING: no console will be available to OS
   >   error: no suitable video mode found.
   >   [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/349Kh.jpg)
5. While keeping the partitions/all settings as setup by my explanation in the fourth item (above), I tried the link in the second item above because GRUB was installed. I could access the menu and I ran through everything needed to be done. However, upon reboot, I ran into the same indefinite blank screen.
6. In accordance with [@TheMysteriousMan's](https://askubuntu.com/users/171722/themysteriousman) post, I've also tried selecting `/dev/sda1` to install the boot loader on, but I received the same error.
7. The Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit, Mac alternate) has been tried also, but again, the same error is received.
8. Something I've noticed is that when double clicking on a partition (while in the installation process seen in the 3rd photo of this post) and bringing up the "Edit partition" window, under the "Use as:" drop down (where options like "Ext4 journaling file system" appear), I have the option "Reserved BIOS boot area." I'm wondering if the error is asking me to do something with the option. If it is asking me to use this option, should I create a new partition and set this option on it? How big should the partition be? Or do I put it on an existing partition?

---

### TLDR & The Question

The main question here is: how do I get by this error message? Is there some configuration I have to do that I haven't already? Or is this a safe error message to bypass?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read the **whole** answer **before** following the instructions below.

In order to fix this issue you need to create an extra partition.

1. Install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) or [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)<sup>1</sup> in Ubuntu.
2. Start Mac OS X.
3. Launch OS the Disk Utility application.
4. Make sure to have **already** resized your "Macintosh HD" partition so that you have room for the new partitions (~50 GiB is what I chose).
5. Restart using a Ubuntu Live CD.
6. Select "Try Ubuntu".
7. Start the application named GParted.
8. Create a new partition called "bootloader" with file system ReiserFS. I made this partition 500 MiB. *I'm not exactly sure if the file system or size matters. According to [Wikipedia BIOS Boot partition page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition), this partition can be as small as only 1 MiB.*
9. Create a new linux-swap partition that's about 1 GiB. I called this one "swap".
10. Create an ext4 partition called "primary" using the rest of your unallocated space.

After following the instructions above, GParted should look similar to the following image. Keep in mind that I took this after installation. The labels for my linux-swap and ext4 partitions disappeared and the key/exclamation icons were added after installation by Ubuntu. Also, no need to set a `bios_grub` flag for the ResiserFS partition, this was also automatically added post- (or during-) installation.
[image: GParted]

Now that the partitions are set up, go back to the desktop, click on "Install Ubuntu 12.04" (this should also appear in the menubar on the left if it's not on the desktop), and follow along below

1. Go through the options (personalizing them however you like) until you get to the "Installation type" screen that asks you how you want to install Ubuntu.
2. On the "Installation type" screen, select "Something else" and continue (press "Install Now").
3. You'll now arrive at a window that lists all the partitions you have. Identify the "bootloader" partition (if the labels don't show, identify it by the device, type, or size columns) and double click on it.
4. A window that says "Edit partition" should popup. Select the option field next to "Use as:" and click on the value that says "Reserved BIOS boot area" (figure below). Press "OK."
   [image: Select "Reserved BIOS boot area"]
5. Identify the ext4 partition you just created and bring up the "Edit partition" window.
6. Set the "Use as:" value to "Ext4 journaling file system," check the format option. Make sure to also set the mount field to `/`. Press "OK."
7. Go ahead and continue the process, personalizing the results as you desire.

From here, everything should work fine. Make sure to have rEFIt or rEFInd installed so that you can boot into Ubuntu later<sup>1</sup>.

> <sup>1. It turns out that if you get stuck while booting, instead of using a program like rEFIt and it's predecessor, you can just hold the <kbd>alt/option</kbd> key to boot into a partition/disk/whatever.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

The last time I checked (two or three releases ago), the "Mac alternate" version of Ubuntu was basically just the normal Ubuntu but stripped of its EFI boot options. This may seem peculiar, since Macs use EFI, but the problem is that the Mac's EFI is *weird*, and the standard Ubuntu installer had problems with the Mac's EFI. (I don't recall the precise nature of the problems, though.) Since Macs provide a BIOS compatibility layer, booting in that way makes sense; and when GRUB installs to a GPT disk using a BIOS boot mode, use of a [BIOS Boot Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition) (what the Ubuntu dialog box refers to as a "reserved BIOS boot area") is necessary. Hence, the dialog box asking for that area.

One option for how to proceed is to acquiesce with the request to create a BIOS Boot Partition. Ubuntu will then boot in BIOS mode, if all goes well. You can subsequently change the Linux boot mode by installing an EFI-mode boot loader. See my [EFI-Booting Ubuntu on a Mac](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html) for one example of how to do this, and particularly the section entitled ["Fixing the Installation."](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html#fixing)

Another option is to try using the standard Ubuntu installer rather than the Mac variant. You may need some help getting it to boot; it's possible that [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) will help with that, although I can make no promises. Once the installer is booted, you should ensure that it's running in EFI mode by looking for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode, and if it's not present, you've probably booted in BIOS mode and should try again.

Comment: Thanks! I've run into a few problems when following the "Installing Ubuntu" section. I've installed gdisk, but the commands don't work. When running `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0s3` I get "Error is 16." So, I tried deleting it manually in Disk Utility and creating a new partition via gdisk (with `n`), but then I get "Error is 2." I couldn't find any docs, but since you're the developer, I'm hoping you could shed light on this issue.

Comment: You're specifying a partition (`/dev/disk0s3`) as an option to `gdisk`, but you need to specify the *whole disk* (`/dev/disk0`).

Comment: I messed up. I put "+128M" as the first sector instead of the last. It's prompting me for the last sector. What should I do? =/ (If you want to go into the "General Room" chat room, that'd be great :D)

Comment: Hit Ctrl+C to break out of the program and try again.

Comment: I have no idea how to do step 1 under step 10 of "Fixing the Installation" (starts with "Copy an EFI driver for the filesystem you used on /boot (or your root filesystem, if you didn't split off /boot)...") To be honest, I wouldn't even know what to search. Do you have any simpler instructions? :) Thanks so far.

Comment: The EFI drivers are stored in the `refind-{version}/refind/drivers_x64` subdirectory when you extract the rEFInd `.zip` file, or under that subdirectory of `/usr/share` if you install rEFInd from a Debian package file. See the [rEFInd documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) for more information.

Comment: Okay. For step 4 under 10, wasn't sure if I needed to add or replace, so I tried both. They both displayed a black screen that stayed there for up to ten minutes (at which point I just rebooted). So I continued with the regular instructions and instead of step 18 working correctly, I got the following error: [`WARNING: no console will be available to OS / error: no suitable video mode found.`](http://i.imgur.com/yD5OTGO.jpg) I found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#.22No_suitable_mode_found.22_error), but wasn't sure if it was applicable and it seemed awfully confusing.

Comment: Step 4 in the "Update" box just after step 10 clearly states "add." It might not have worked for any number of reasons, including bugs and user error; it's impossible to diagnose the reason without much more back-and-forth. As to the failure when you followed the original steps through to step #18, that unfortunately indicates a problem with the kernel's (and perhaps X's) ability to use the computer's video hardware, at least when booted in EFI mode. I'm afraid I don't know of an easy solution to this problem.

Comment: I was aware that it said "add," but wasn't sure if I was supposed to add the change to `ro root`, or add the whole thing. Thanks for your help this far. Hopefully a bounty will be offered on this question.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to choose `/dev/sda1` as the place to install your bootloader? On the bottom of the custom installation menu, there is a place marked:

```
Device for bootloader installation
```

Choose /dev/sda1 from the dropdown menu.

Comment: This was what I meant earlier in the chat room.  Just pick your EFI partition on your main disk as the bootloader location.  According to Wikipedia, this may affect later firmware updates, but my mac was old enough I didn't really care (not likely to be any useful updates).

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh and OP: Unfortunately this didn't work. Thanks, though.