# Unable to boot into Ubuntu 13.04 on Mac

Tags: boot, live-usb, macbook-pro, boot-partition

Today I decided to erase OS X and install Ubuntu - unfortunately something went wrong and now I am asking this question on live mode on Ubuntu.

So basically all I did was create a bootable USB stick from OS X, restarted, then held down <kbd>⌥</kbd> = 'alt/option*, choosed the stick, installed Ubuntu and erased OS X.

All was good, and after installion it said: "**successful installation**" and restarted the computer. I did that, and a blinking question mark appeared on the screen. My MBP could not find any bootable partition.

Any idea what can I do to get Ubuntu up and running?

By the way, I want to point out there is no OS X partition left on my drive - I didn't use any kind of program for dual boot, since I wanted to install OS X on another physical drive.

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316893/error-partition-table-requires-a-separate-partition-for-boot-loader-code-efi-i) answer in terms of the booting setup, also.

Answer (score 0):

your installation failed, i strongly suspect, because 
you didn't create a proper boot on the drive.

Try installing it again but this time you
will want to create your partitions manually.
First create a /boot and give it 250mb
then create your root  /root and give it 12gb -15gb
then create your swap  /swap and give it 2048mb
then create your home  /home and give it the rest of the drive.
I have found this setup works beautifully and is
extremely stable