# MacBook Pro 9.2, trying to single install Ubuntu. Encountering problems after restart

Tags: system-installation, restart, macbook-pro

Just in case you are wondering, I am asking this from "try Ubuntu without installing".

This is where I'm at:

I have a **MacBook Pro 9.2** (according to terminal).

I have **completely** got rid of Mac OS X (Personal files backed up on Ubuntu One).

I have done an install of **Ubuntu 12.04** from a DVD that I mounted the .iso file onto.

After advice from another post, I made a point of partitioning the 500GB Hard Drive as follows:

```
dev/sda1: fat32         Size - 953Mb.      Used: 3.94Mb. Flags: boot
dev/sda2: linux-swap    Size - 7.45Gb.     Used: --      Flags: --
dev/sda3: ext4          Size - 37.25Gb.    Used: 3.81Gb  Flags: --
dev/sda4: ext4          Size - 420.13Gb.   Used: 6.80Gb  Flags: --
```

When doing the partitioning I intended to make sda4 a /home thing.

Also it recommended creating a EFI boot thing. This I believe to be sda1.

So I completed the installation, and no issues/errors were presented.

At the end of it, the system told me to restart. So I pressed "Restart Now" (only option).

Subsequently it told me to remove the installation media and hit enter, I obliged.

It then restarted, and I got a white screen (typical of an OS X boot up).

After a while it came up with a blinking file logo, indicating that it has not found the Operating System???

Anyone got any clues?

Thanks :)

Comment: See if the recommended EFI boot thing was as described in this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316893/error-partition-table-requires-a-separate-partition-for-boot-loader-code-efi-i. If so, follow my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I see that your problem is that the 'boot' flag is linked to an FAT file system. Since you are planning only ubuntu in your system you should link the boot drive to an ext4 file system. In other words, the booting drive should be from an ext partition. Trust this helps.

Comment: Do you know about EFI boot and GPT partitions? I think you're referring to legacy BIOS boot setup which does not apply to Apple and other UEFI-only devices.