# How to install Ubuntu dual boot with MacBook Pro refind?

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10, macbook-pro

I need help installing Ubuntu 15.10 on a Macbook pro. I would like it as a dual boot. Please help!

Comment: What's the problem with just starting the installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: partition table requires a separate partition for boot loader code (EFI issue)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316893/error-partition-table-requires-a-separate-partition-for-boot-loader-code-efi-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives a good example of how to install Ubuntu on a mac: http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/

Mac boot camp, only works for windows, it will refuse to go forward without a usable windows disk. Do not fret though because there are easy work arounds to get Ubuntu or any linux distro on your mac. The above URL is a pretty good step by step instruction on how to install Ubuntu without having to worry about bootcamp.

Comment: Bootcamp doesn't help to install Linux, it's Windows only! Right when you open it, it asks for Windows ISO otherwise it won't go forward.

Comment: Okay, you are right, I forgot how the actual steps went since it has been a while since I have had a mac. In that case just use the second URL to install linux on a mac. So I'll change my answer to show that.